# Directory root not being set with the procfile

Tags: heroku, lumen

So I've gotten my installation of lumen onto heroku but it seems like it cant find the root directory since it doesn't load `index.php` at all which is in the `/public directory`.

My procfile contains:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

my directory

```
bol_importer
├── app
├── bootstrap
├── database
├── public
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── .htacces
├── resources
├── routes
├── storage
├── tests
├── vendor
├── .editorconfig
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── artisan
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── phpunit.xml
└── Procfile
```

This is also being displayed in the heroku dashboard.

Has anyone else encountered this before and can help me?

Comment: Is your file called `procfile` or `Procfile`? Those are different things, and Heroku expects the latter. Your title and question both say `procfile`, but your "directory listing" shows `Procfile`.

Comment: Also, what does "it doesn't load `index.php`" mean? Does deployment succeed? What happens when you try to load your site in a browser? What do you see in your logs? Please read [ask].